# Temporary object and non-const reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I can't figure out why I keep getting a compilation error when using the following code.

A simple structure and its init helper function:

```
typedef struct _ccColor4F 
{
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
    GLfloat a; 
} ccColor4F;

static inline ccColor4F  ccc4f(const GLfloat r, const GLfloat g, const GLfloat b, const GLfloat a)  
{
    ccColor4F c4 = {r, g, b, a};
    return c4; 
}
```

and a  method using the structure:

```
void TexturePolygon::setColor(ccColor4F &color);
```

Now if I try to use the init function as follow I get a compilation error.

```
poly->setColor(ccc4f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f));
```

> non-const lvalue reference to type 'ccColor4F' (aka 'cocos2d::_ccColor4F') cannot bind to a temporary of type 'ccColor4F'

I have to change the parameter of setColor to a  "const reference" to avoid the error. I understand that a temporary object must be bound to a const reference. But in this case it's an inline function so there shouldn't be any temporary object. Am I missing something?

Thanks. Laurent

Comment: I'm not sure why you think `inline` would make any difference here.

Comment: `inline` allows you to define the function in multiple translation units (which, for many compilers, is necessary to inline calls to it). It doesn't force calls to be inlined, or change any of its semantics. A reference argument is still treated as a reference, even if it's optimised out.

Comment: @FredLarson I thought `inline` would have changed the semantics of the call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function being `inline` has no bearing on weather or not the object is a temporary.

`inline` doesn't do what you think it does.  It doesn't even do what many people think it does.

What `inline` does is make it so that a function can be defined in multiple translation units.  What `inline` **doesn't** do is make the code expand inline (it's a hint, not a requirement.  The compiler can and will ignore you.), not does it have any effect on the semantics of the call, the parameters or the returns.

In your code:

```
poly->setColor(ccc4f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f));
```

The object constructed by `ccc4f(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f)`  **is** a temporary.  The fact that `setColor()` is `inline` makes no difference.

If you need to send a non-temporary to `setColor()`, then you have to construct a non-temporary `ccc4f`:

```
ccc4f myObj(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
poly->setColor (myObj);
```

You could scope this so that `myObj` is destroyed right after you call `setColor`:

```
{
  ccc4f myObj(1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f);
  poly->setColor (myObj);
}
```

But that seems rather pointless as `myObj` doesn't appear to be an RAII object.  Why not just have `setColor` accept a `const` reference and be done with it?

Comment: ok. I get it now. I was wrong thinking inline might change the semantics of the call. PS: I'll change to const reference. It's just I didn't understand why I had to in this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your `setColor` function expects to get an assignable memory reference, meaning it should be able to do

```
color = NULL;
```

if it so desires. Your code doesn't allow for that, because you're giving a temporary object.

What's the reasoning here? Either the `setColor` function changes the `color` parameter, in which case it doesn't make sense giving it a temporary object; or the `setColor` function doesn't change the `color` parameter, in which case it should be passed as a const-reference.